# Can't access super user in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, su

I am trying to login to my Ubuntu terminal as super user, but terminal says `"Cannot execute :No such file or directory"`

output from terminal :

```
gowtham@gowtham:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for gowtham:
Cannot execute gowtham: No such file or directory
gowtham@gowtham:~$
```

where "gowtham" is my username.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on, but you may be able to get the effect you would like with `sudo -i`.

Comment: I tried sudo -i ,
but terminal says
"command not found"

Comment: Check what default shell is set for the root user: `cat /etc/passwd`. Maybe a default shell "gowtham" is set which does not exist and therefore cannot be executed.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` give you?

Comment: echo $PATH gives :
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin

Comment: I tried to fin default shell by `echo $SHELL`
it provides : /bin/zsh

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show us the content of `/etc/passwd` as I asked my previous comment

Comment: As a workaround, try `sudo bash`.

Comment: Not a programming question; nominating to close as off-topic. Maybe flag for moderator attention and request migration e.g. to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: sorry mnille.
 gowtham@gowtham:~$ sudo /etc/passwd

[sudo] password for gowtham: 
sudo: /etc/passwd: command not found

gowtham@gowtham:~$

Comment: thank you so much tripleee..
finally it worked.
gowtham@gowtham:~$ sudo bash


root@gowtham:~#

Comment: @Gowtham: `/etc/passwd`should be world-readable, so do not have to be root to see the content of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passwd file might be wrong. Try editing it:

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

Edit it from:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:somerandomfile
```

to

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you so much cristian, I changed as you said., it got worked, now `sudo su` is perfectly working for me.

Comment: 'root' account disabled for security reason in Ubuntu, you provided with `sudo` to execute commands as root (it is considered more secure way). If you enabled 'shell' for user account then assign a password as well to root user and you do not need do `sudo su`, just `su` will be sufficient. [How to Enable and Disable Root User Account in Ubuntu](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-and-disable-root-user-account-in-ubuntu/), [su](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html)